# How to implement Linear gradient in Xamarin android?

Tags: xamarin.android

I want to implement something like the image I have attached in my application dynamically.But I don't know how to specify the centercolor,startcolor,endcolor and angle in C# Gradient [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mM6zI.png)

how to implement this programmatically in Xamarin android native platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**GradientActivity.cs**

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.GradientLayout);

    ImageView ivTest = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.ivSquare);
    GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(
        GradientDrawable.Orientation.TrBl,  // "Top Right, Bottom Left"
        new int[] { new Color(Color.Red), new Color(Color.White), new Color(Color.Blue) });
    ivTest.Background = gd;
}
```

**GradientLayout.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >
  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:id="@+id/ivSquare" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Output**

[image: Example Output]

Comment: Thank You @Robert.Its fine, but in my case the image is not exactly a square.So middle color is not exactly at the diagonal.Do you have any idea about how to divide it diagonally??

Comment: @BBB, I answered your question precisely as presented and recommend accepting my answer so others can benefit from it.  Then, create a new question regarding the diagonal division, and we can go from there.